# How to remove nofollow link from woocommerce add to cart button using woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link hook?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I added this to functions.php. Is there any best solution than this?

```
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link',
global $product;    
return sprintf( '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    ),
$product );
```

Comment: hi, is this the default of wordpress wocommerce to have nofollow on their links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will also be able to modify the link follow this:

```
return sprintf( '<button href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</button>',
    esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
    esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
    esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
    esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
),$product );
```

Answer (score 2):

At https://www.curlsforyou.dk a site build with WordPress and standard woocommerce I have managed to run this snip with success:

Simply insert the code in Code Snippets plugin and, the `nofollow` links are now dofollow.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'add_to_cart_dofollow', 10, 2 );
function add_to_cart_dofollow($html, $product){
    $html = sprintf( '<a rel="dofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $class ) ? $class : 'button' ),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    );
    return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this code. But did not find how to insert in "aria-label" product title.

```
// Change rel “nofollow” to rel “dofollow” on Shop Page Product button
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'add_to_cart_dofollow', 10, 2 );
function add_to_cart_dofollow($html, $product){
    if($product->product_type == 'simple') {
        $html = sprintf( '<a rel="nofollow" href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" aria-label="Добавить в корзину" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button product_type_variable add_to_cart_button' ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : ''),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    );
    }else {
    $html = sprintf( '<a href="%s" data-quantity="%s" data-product_id="%s" aria-label="Выбрать" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s" %s>%s</a>',
        esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $quantity ) ? $quantity : 1 ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_id() ),
        esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['class'] ) ? $args['class'] : 'button product_type_variable add_to_cart_button' ),
        esc_attr( isset( $args['attributes'] ) ? wc_implode_html_attributes( $args['attributes'] ) : ''),
        esc_html( $product->add_to_cart_text() )
    );
    }
    return $html;
}
```